# find time between json field array on MySql

Tags: mysql, json

I have an `availability` table with the following structure

```
| id | weekday | interval                                     |
| 1  |  0      | {"open":"1583055000","close":"1583087400"}   |
| 2  |  0      | {"open":"1583069400","close":"1583086200"}   |
```

How can I search for a specific time between the open and close fields?

I tried:

```
select * from availabilities where json_extract(`interval`, "$.open") > 1583063400 and json_extract(`interval`, "$.close") < 1583063400;
```

but returns 0 results

Comment: You'll have to use [JSON_TABLE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html). Out of curiosity, why are you storing these in a JSON array instead of in normal columns, one row per open/close pair? It would be a lot easier to solve the query.

Comment: each line represents an appointment, has the day of the week column and the interval column contains the service hours

Comment: Ok you've just edited the example data, to remove the array in the JSON and make it a single object. Which is it, an array or an object?

Comment: @BillKarwin thanks for your suggestion, I made the change that suggested new open/close pairs (single object), but I still didn't understand how to perform this query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with JSON is full of pitfalls.

First, if you JSON_EXTRACT(), you don't get a string or a number, you get another JSON document, although one that is just a single string.

```
mysql> select json_extract(`interval`, '$.open') from availabilities;
+------------------------------------+
| json_extract(`interval`, '$.open') |
+------------------------------------+
| "1583055000"                       |
| "1583069400"                       |
+------------------------------------+
```

So you also need to unquote the value to get a plain scalar value. Read about [JSON_UNQUOTE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-unquote).

```
mysql> select json_unquote(json_extract(`interval`, '$.open')) from availabilities;
+--------------------------------------------------+
| json_unquote(json_extract(`interval`, '$.open')) |
+--------------------------------------------------+
| 1583055000                                       |
| 1583069400                                       |
+--------------------------------------------------+
```

You can also use the `->>` shorthand to do the same as extract and unquote:

```
mysql> select `interval`->>'$.open' from availabilities
+-----------------------+
| `interval`->>'$.open' |
+-----------------------+
| 1583055000            |
| 1583069400            |
+-----------------------+
```

The other problem with your query is that you have conditions that are never true for your data values. Let's show you why:

```
select
  open, open > 1583063400 as gt1583063400,
  close, close < 1583063400 as lt1583063400
from (
  select
    json_unquote(json_extract(`interval`, '$.open')) as open,
    json_unquote(json_extract(`interval`, '$.close')) as close
  from availabilities
) as t

+------------+--------------+------------+--------------+
| open       | gt1583063400 | close      | lt1583063400 |
+------------+--------------+------------+--------------+
| 1583055000 |            0 | 1583087400 |            0 |
| 1583069400 |            1 | 1583086200 |            0 |
+------------+--------------+------------+--------------+
```

Neither of the close values you have in your data are less than the value you're comparing them to.

In your query, you want rows where both the open AND the close pass the conditions you've given. Maybe you meant to use OR?

Anyway, if you change the value you're comparing to, you can find one row where both pass.

```
select
  open, open > 1583063400 as gt1583063400,
  close, close < 1583087200 as lt1583087200
from (
  select
    json_unquote(json_extract(`interval`, '$.open')) as open,
    json_unquote(json_extract(`interval`, '$.close')) as close
  from availabilities
) as t

+------------+--------------+------------+--------------+
| open       | gt1583063400 | close      | lt1583087200 |
+------------+--------------+------------+--------------+
| 1583055000 |            0 | 1583087400 |            0 |
| 1583069400 |            1 | 1583086200 |            1 |
+------------+--------------+------------+--------------+
```